# Controlling out with Apply function

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I have been asked to do the following:
Print the `summary` of `AtmWtAg.wide`. Use a function from the apply family (`apply`, `tapply`, `lapply`,`sapply`) and the appropriate R functions to compute a similar set of values (column-wise mean, median, min, max and quantiles).

Note that each column in this format are observations from a single machine.
The data AtmWtAf.wide looks like this:

```
              1           2
1   107.8681568 107.8681079     
2   107.8681465 107.8681344     
3   107.8681572 107.8681513     
4   107.8681785 107.8681197     
5   107.8681446 107.8681604     
6   107.8681903 107.8681385
```

I tried this, but my data is in rows instead of columns and the structure is not a data.frame.  We have been asked not to physically change the summary by as.data.frame.  We aren't supposed to just use the general summary statement either.

```
AtmWtag.wide1 <- apply(AtmWtAg.wide, 2, function(x) c(mean(x),median(x),quantile(x)))
```

Comment: Use `dput(head(AtmWtAg.wide))` to make a reproducible example.

Comment: You're being asked to do something that's more or less impossible, as none of the `*apply` functions return a data.frame. You could use `data.frame` instead of `as.data.frame`, but that's just bad style to skirt the rules. The unmentioned `aggregate` seems appropriate, but is limited/finicky compared to dplyr or data.table alternatives.